# python: multiple pattern with spaces

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm trying to find simpler way to search multiple patterns which are part of a sentences. eg.

```
1: this is my first line
2: this is second
3: and many more such lines.
```

pat = 'my first|many more|not there'.
output should be only these 2 patterns = 'my first' and 'many more'.

so i'll loop through all lines and want to find patterns which are found from these lines and the result should be one match per line.

```
pat = re.compile(r'.*(my first|many more|not there).*')
for val in data_lines:
  x = pat.findall(val)
  if x:
     print(x)
```

the problem i believe is spaces, but i want to avoid any modification to pat like (my\sfirst). Is there any better way to keep code slim and achieve the results ?

Comment: Can you post exactly what result are you getting and what would you expect in this example? The code looks fine and spaces in the pattern are not a problem.

Comment: the result would be only the patterns that were found in lines, i.e 'my first' and 'many more'. the problem is if i dont add \s in each pattern it doesn't give any results.

Comment: Sorry for this post, i found that the actual data had a hidden non-ascii char due to which it was not working. my code is working.

Comment: Sorry about this add on query, which i'm trying to find to avoid the presence of non-ascii chars in rows. Is there any way to skip bad rows during df operations like df.str.split etc.? I can see "on_bad_lines" option while reading df but how to catch if any errors later which are beyond on_bad_lines? eg. we use try: except: logic so anything similar in pandas cmnd? Also i dont see even with "on_bad_lines" we can  control the format for allowed data per column. please help in case i missed something.